# SHA1 Hash Delphi vs Python

Tags: python, delphi, hash, sha1

I try to hash the same string in delphi and python but i get different hashes ?

**Python:**

```
d = bytes('pr', 'utf-8')
print((sha1(d).digest()).hex())

output: 5498d9b96ed2832e04a90c4ac2ab71f869b2bfdc
```

**Delphi XE7:**

```
...
bytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('pr');
BinToHex(sha1Digest2(bytes);
...
output: 1ca1a00b40b8350d15cdce2935965d88b7798719


Function TForm1.sha1Digest2(buffer: TBytes): TBytes;
Var
  HashSHA1: THashSHA1;
Begin
  HashSHA1 := THashSHA1.Create;
  HashSHA1.Update(buffer, SizeOf(buffer));
  Result := HashSHA1.HashAsBytes;
End;

Function TForm1.binToHex(Const bin: Array Of Byte): String;
Const
  HexSymbols = '0123456789ABCDEF';
Var
  I: Integer;
Begin
  SetLength(Result, 2 * Length(bin));
  For I := 0 To Length(bin) - 1 Do
  Begin
    Result[1 + 2 * I + 0] := HexSymbols[1 + bin[I] Shr 4];
    Result[1 + 2 * I + 1] := HexSymbols[1 + bin[I] And $0F];
  End;
End;
```

What i'm doing wrong ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you confirm that `bytes` has a length of two and contains `{0x70, 0x72}`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Solved. thanks you too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `Sizeof(buffer)` instead of `Length(buffer)`! So you are hashing 4 bytes instead of 2. `Sizeof(<TBytes>)` is always 4 as internally it is a pointer.

Comment: If you omit the length parameter, `Update()` will use the full size of the byte array: `HashSHA1.Update(buffer);`